# vSphere Powercli - The specified privileges are from a different server

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli, vsphere

I have the following powercli script to add a local account to an esx host. 
With all my research I believe this should work but when I run it I get this error.

```
    New-VIRole : 3/04/2014 9:23:49 a.m.    New-VIRole        The specified privileges are from a different server.    
At .\test.ps1:18 char:11
+ New-VIRole <<<<  -Name "CIM Only" -Privilege "CIM interaction" 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (VMware.VimAutom...ent.Privilege[]:Privilege[]) [New-VIRole], VimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_NewVIRole_DoWork_PrivilegeFromDifferentServerSpecified,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.PermissionManagement.NewVIRole`
```

Here is the script

```
## As usual, load needed PowerCLI cmdlets  
asnp VMware.VimAutomation.Core -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue      

# Define the ESXi server  
$server = "servername"    

#Connect to ESXi server  
Connect-VIServer -Server $server -user user -password password  

#Create a new role CIM, with the only needed privilege assigned to it  
New-VIRole -Name "CIM Only" -Privilege "CIM interaction" 

#Create the cimuser account, assign it to root group, and deny it shell access  
New-VMHostAccount -Id cimuser -Password password -UserAccount:$true -AssignGroups root -GrantShellAccess:$false

#Assign the role CIM to the newly created cimuser account  
New-VIPermission -Entity $server -Principal cimuser -Role "CIM Only" 

#Disconnect from ESXi server  
Disconnect-VIServer -Server $server -Confirm:$false
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
New-VIRole -Name "CIM Only" -Privilege ( Get-VIPrivilege "CIM interaction" )
```

What esxi version are you running?